# Messages app in Android triggers GET links without user interaction

Tags: android, sms, message, preview

I'm sending a confirmation link via SMS to my user.

When the SMS arrives on the device, a GET request is triggered to the link **without** any user interaction, thus confirming my appointment.

Is there a way to detect if the GET request was triggered by the user or some preview or security get request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, the Google Messages app tries to get a preview of the url.

I found this user agent

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36 Google (+https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)
```

Now I'm simply ignoring user agents with the string `snippet`.

Comment: I just noticed Google Messages started doing this. I wonder if this is going to become a thing on other messaging clients. Also turns out Chrome is about to kill the user agent as it currently is, so not sure what options we'll have to ignore links that are automatically hit by the client to grab a preview.

Comment: @adrian Chrome is going to kill sending a ua? do you have a link for this?

Comment: @ClaytonRothschild - here are a couple: 
https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-to-phase-out-user-agent-strings-in-chrome/ https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/01/14/chrome-wants-to-kill-browser-user-agent-strings-cites-compatibility-and-privacy-concerns/